# Items in a playlist rotation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to know the name of the effect in which "Items in a playlist rotates/appears/scrolls in a loop". I mean after the 'x' seconds, an image disappears and next the image appears in the playlist until the end of playlist at which point the first item in playlist appears.

It would be helpful to get some search terms for google and if somebody has already asked this on stack, please point me to that. Any pointers to code-snippets would be useful

PS: I am just learning HTML/CSS/jQuery/JS etc. I am not sure which bucket this lies into. I got few negative votes for my previous question even though it got answered and was valid. Please pardon my ignorance.

Please assign it to a different bucket if needed.

Comment: if you're looking for "Do something after 'x' seconds" - try looking up `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`. Simple example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var count = 0;
var amount = $(".playlist-items").length;

setInterval(function(){
    count >= amount-1 ? count = 0 : count++;

    // do your fade/show here, using 'count'.

}, 5000);
```

The above would simply perform an infinite loop every 5 seconds, giving you a variable `count` to indicate where you're at in the loop.

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Wp8dh/